# Just installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 and my network doesn't seem to connect

Tags: networking, gnome, 15.10

I've just done a fresh install of Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 and my network doesn't connect at all.

I've updated my driver to the latest version to the best of my abilities (new Linux, so I hope I've done it right. Followed the README so I assume so)

All my outputs: [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7ee6219dfa0e06ef7cfb843e7031a107)

```
/etc/network/interfaces + /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]  
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono  
dns=dnsmasq  

[ifupdown]  
managed=false
```

More details from `/var/log/syslog` can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d30984c98956c2d4d5ab5d7468ff341a)

Comment: Did you (accidentally) disable the Onboard Lan in the BIOS settings?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean the onboard LAN doesn't work on windows either? (I should have mentioned this is a dual-boot installation)

Comment: Yes. So that's not the problem here.

Comment: Other things to check: `/etc/networking/interfaces/`  and `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. Please paste them into your question.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, updated first question with the updated info

Answer (score 0):

This is a familiar error, in fact it happens so often that it might be seen as a bug.

Edit the file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and change "managed=false" to "managed=true". Then do `sudo service NetworkManager restart`. After a while, your network connections will be OK.

Comment: I tried this and unfortuantely it didn't seem to work. I did in the meantime reinstall Ubuntu and this time went for the standard installation so my driver was again downgraded to an older version. Trying a reinstall of that now to see if that helps or not.

Comment: Ok, reinstalled the latest driver and tried again. Unfortunately this didn't fix it for me and the network still cannot connect

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial and error and help from a friend
`sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 eno1` fixed my problem